# redirect to a page from apex in the constructor

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, controller, redirect

I have a method in the page constructor that checks if a user has access to the page. If not, I want to redirect the user to another "Access Denied" page. I know I can use Pagereferences as part of a VF page and return to the page. But since I do my validation in the constructor, I cannot do that. Any solutions to resolve the issue?

Comment: use <apex:page> action attribute to call pagereference method

Comment: In addition to the answers, I'd like to mention something neither of them did: the action method on the `apex:page` element runs after the constructor but before the page is rendered, so the user won't see "part of an interface" or some such. They'll be cleanly redirected to the correct page if a PageReference is returned from the action method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't redirect from constructor so you need to use the apex:page action attribute for that.

```
<apex:page controller="YOURCONTROLLERNAME" action="{!YOURMETHODNAME}">
</apex:page>
```

Your Apex Method:

```
 public PageReference validateAndRedirect(){

      //Write your logic here and redirect
      PageReference retURL = new PageReference('REDIRECT URL');
      retURL.setRedirect(true);
      return retURL;

 }
```

Comment: Note that your users may get an error when they try to view the page, ***Insufficient Privileges***. If so, got to `Setup` and search for `Visualforce Pages`. Then find your page, and click on `Security`, and ensure that "Standard User" is added to the users allowed to access that page, and hit `Save`. More [details can be found here](http://visualforcemadeeasy.blogspot.ca/2009/02/insufficient-privileges-users-can-not.html)

Answer (score 3):

use `<apex:page>` action attribute to call pagereference method

VF page.

```
<apex:page controller="myCtrl" action="{!pageReferenceMethod}">


</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class myCtrl{

    public myCtrl()
    {

    }

    public PageReference pageReferenceMethod()
    {
          return new PageReference('/001');
     }

}
```